# Karate - get URL from <a> element using Javascript

Tags: automated-tests, karate

Using Karate, I need to extract the url from  tag (href). I have tried this using Javascript directly in browser:

```
document.querySelector('a[rel="noopener"]').href
```

It works in browser fine, I receive whole url address ("https://XXXXXXXX"). Then I wanted to place it to Karate using:

```
   * def emailLink =
   """
   function(){
      var link = document.querySelector('a[rel="noopener"]').href;
      return link;
   }
   """
  * print emailLink()
```

But it does not work. The variable = "". I need to receive the href value.

Have you any Idea how to solve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you are writing will not work, and please read this to understand why: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#karate-vs-the-browser

So make this change (and also note how Karate does `document.querySelector()` for you):

```
* def linkElement = locate('a[rel="noopener"]')
* def linkValue = linkElement.attribute('href')
```

Note that for the second line this should also work:

```
* def linkValue = linkElement.script('_.href')
```

Or even this:

```
* def linkValue = linkElement.property('href')
```

Start getting used to the `Element` abstraction in Karate. It can be very useful: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#chaining

Comment: Many thanks! It works as expected. Solved.

Answer (score 1):

I have just been reading https://intuit.github.io/karate/ and for just JavaScript you don't need the multi-line doc string.

```
* def greeter = function(title, name) { return 'hello ' + title + ' ' + name }
```

Try without the """ on either side of the function """.